# Headphones don't work on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, headphones

Installed Xubuntu and headphones don't work. I had similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04 (headphones didn't work sometimes), I had to log out to fix the issue but this doesn't work on Xubuntu.

I also tried to uninstall pulseaudio, played with alsamixer and pavucontrol nothing solved the issue.

Headphones perfectly work on  Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try a tool like "Sound Switcher Indicator" first to make sure it is really a driver issue and not a problem caused through choosing the wrong output source? ;-)

https://yktoo.com/en/software/indicator-sound-switcher

Onboard sound with digital and anolog out, maybe a graphic card with a digital audio out too, this can be very confusing. The tool is very handy to get a quick overview which output source is active at the moment.

Comment: I found a solution (at least headphones started working). I just shut down the laptop and turned it on again.